# Display result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure. I want Total Leave Days, in particular Month and Year wise. Also I have mention my expected output.

```
Table : 1
tblAbsent

Id  Code      LeaveDate Leave   LeaveDay
934 002DSK  2018-08-10  EL      1
934 002DSK  2018-08-11  EL      1
934 002DSK  2018-08-12  EL      1
934 002DSK  2018-09-10  EL      1
934 002DSK  2018-10-12  EL      1
934 002DSK  2018-10-13  EL      1
934 002DSK  2018-10-14  EL      1
934 002DSK  2018-10-15  EL      1

Table : 2 tblEmpdetails

Id          Code    tblAbsentID Month   Year
1172        002DSK  934         4       2018
1259        002DSK  934         5       2018
1335        002DSK  934         6       2018
1411        002DSK  934         7       2018
1487        002DSK  934         8       2018
1563        002DSK  934         9       2018
1639        002DSK  934        10       2018
1715        002DSK  934        11       2018
1791        002DSK  934        12       2018
Table : 3 LeaveOpening

Id      tblAbsentId  Leave  LeaveOpen
80      934          EL      24
```

I have tried to result with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    et.EmployeeId
   ,Month AS [Monthnumber]
   ,DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, Month, -1)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), Year, 103) AS [Calendar Year Of Service]
   ,CONCAT('1-', et.MD) AS [Wages during From...To...]
   ,et.PD AS [No. Of Days Work Performed], 
   --sum(lb.HFDay) as EL,
   lo.LeaveOpening

   ,(SELECT
            SUM(lb.HFDay)
        FROM dbo.tblAbsent lb
        WHERE lb.EmployeeId = 934 and lb.Leave='EL'  --and lb.LeaveDate >='2018-08-01' and lb.LeaveDate <= '2018-08-30'
        )
    AS EL
    ,(SELECT
            SUM(lb.HFDay)
        FROM dbo.tblAbsent lb
        WHERE lb.EmployeeId = 934 and lb.Leave='ML'
        ) as MaternityLeave
   ,et.PD [Total Of Cols 4 To 7]
   ,ed.FName [Employee Name]
   ,ed.FatherName [Father/Spouses Name]
   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), ed.DateOfJoining, 103) [Date Of Joining Service]

FROM dbo.tblEmpdetails et
INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeDetail ed
    ON et.EmployeeId = ed.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.LeaveOpening lo
ON lo.EmployeeId = et.EmployeeId
inner join dbo.tblAbsent lb on 
lb.EmployeeId = et.EmployeeId
WHERE et.EmployeeId = 934
AND et.CompanyId = 1
AND Category IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND et.ProcessDate >= '2018-01-01'
AND et.ProcessDate <= '2018-12-31' and lb.LeaveDate >='2018-08-01' and lb.LeaveDate <= '2018-08-30'
GROUP BY et.EmployeeId
        ,Month
        ,Year
        ,MD
        ,Gross
        ,PD
        ,ed.FName
        ,ed.FatherName
        ,ed.DateOfJoining
        ,LeaveOpen
```

I am not able to grouping in month wise according to table 2. I want actual output is Sum(LeaveDay) as EL for particular month wise in tblAbsent table.

```
Expected Output:

tblAbsentId Monthnumber Calendar Year Of Service    LeaveOpen   EL
934           4             April - 2018                 24      0
934           5             May - 2018                   24      0
934           6             June - 2018                  24      0
934           7             July - 2018                  24      0
934           8             August - 2018                24      3
934           9             September - 2018             24      1
934          10             October - 2018               24      4
934          11             November - 2018              24      0
934          12             December - 2018              24      0
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created tables shown by you in the above question and also insert same data in the tables. I am able to generate the same output that you expect with below query:

```
SELECT TE.tblAbsentId, TE.Month, TE.Year, LO.LeaveOpen,
    SUM(ISNULL(TA.LeaveDay, 0)) TotalLeave
FROM tblEmpdetails TE
INNER JOIN LeaveOpening LO ON TE.tblAbsentId = LO.tblAbsentId
LEFT JOIN tblAbsent TA ON TE.tblAbsentId = TA.Id AND TE.Month = 
MONTH(TA.LeaveDate) AND TE.Year = YEAR(TA.LeaveDate)
GROUP BY TE.tblAbsentId, TE.Month, TE.Year, LO.LeaveOpen
```

The output of the above query will be as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like below

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/GLK96922)**</kbd>

```
select T.tblAbsentId,
MonthNumber=T.month,
[Calendar year of service]=DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, T.Month, -1)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), Year, 103),
Leaveopen,
EL= COALESCE(s,0)
from tblEmpdetails T
left join 
(
    select 
        id, 
        m=month(leavedate),
        leave, 
        s=sum(leaveday) 
    from tblAbsent 
    group by id, month(leavedate),leave
 ) A
 on T.tblAbsentId=A.id and T.Month=A.m
 left join
 LeaveOpening L 
     on L.tblAbsentid=T.tblAbsentId
```